# How to integrate $\int \frac {\cos^4 x}{\sqrt {1- \sin x}} $

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I frankly don't know where to start. Looked for some identities to get rid of the square root below.

$$\int \frac {\cos^4 x}{\sqrt {1- \sin x}} \, dx  $$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**
if we multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1 + \sin x}$, it becomes

$$\int (\cos^3 x) \, \sqrt {1+\sin x} \, dx $$

Perform the change of variables $ u = \sin x $.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\cos(x)^4 = \cos(x)(1-\sin^2(x))^{3/2} = \cos(x)(1-\sin(x))^{3/2}(1+\sin(x))^{3/2}.$ Thus $$\int \frac{\cos(x)^4}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}dx = \int (1-\sin(x))(1+\sin(x))^{3/2}\cos(x) dx$$ Put $u = \sin(x)$. Then $$\int\frac{\cos(x)^4}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}dx = \int(1-u)(1+u)^{3/2}du.$$ Now put $z = 1+u$ so $$\int\frac{\cos(x)^4}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}dx = \int(2-z)z^{3/2}dz = \int (2z^{3/2} - z^{5/2}) dz = \frac{4}{5} z^{5/2} - \frac{2}{7} z^{7/2} + C.$$ Un-doing the substitutions gives $$\int\frac{\cos(x)^4}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}dx =\frac{4}{5}(1+\sin(x))^{5/2} - \frac{2}{7}(1+\sin(x))^{7/2} + C.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I = \int \frac {\cos^4 x}{\sqrt {1- \sin x}} \, dx  $$
$$\int \frac {\cos^4 x}{\sqrt {1- \sin x}}\frac {\sqrt {1+ \sin x}}{\sqrt {1+ \sin x}} \, dx =\int \frac {\cos^4 x \sqrt {1+ \sin x}}{\sqrt {1- \sin^2 x}}\, dx$$ 
$$\int \cos^3x\,\sqrt {1+ \sin x} dx$$

Set $$t = \sin x\,\quad  dt= -cos x\,dx = -\sqrt{1 -t^2}\, dx \implies dx = dt\frac{1}{-\sqrt{1 -t^2}}$$

$$\int \frac{(\sqrt{1 -t^2})^3\,\sqrt {1+ t}}{-\sqrt{1 -t^2}} dt$$
$$-\int (1 -t^2)\,\sqrt {1+ t}\,dt$$
$$-\int (1 -t)\,(1+ t)^\frac{3}{2}\,dt$$
Apply Integration By Parts:
$$-\left[(1 -t^2)\frac{2}{3}(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} - \int(-2t)\frac{2}{3}(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}}\,dt\right]$$
$$-\left[\frac{2}{3}(1 -t^2)(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{4}{3}\int t(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}}\,dt\right]$$
$\int t(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}}\,dt$
$t\frac{2}{5}(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} - \int 1 \frac{2}{5}(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}}\,dt$
$$-\left[\frac{2}{3}(1 -t^2)(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{4}{3}\left(t\frac{2}{5}(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} - \int 1 \frac{2}{5}(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}}\, dt\right)\right]$$
$$-\left[\frac{2}{3}(1 -t^2)(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{8}{15}t(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{8}{15}\left(\int(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} \,dt\right)\right]$$
$\int(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} \,dt$
Set $u =t + 1\quad du = 1 dt $
$\int u^{\frac{5}{2}} \,du = \frac{u^{\frac{5}{2} + 1}}{\frac{5}{2} + 1} = \frac{2}{7}u^{\frac{7}{2}} = \frac{2}{7}(t+1)^{\frac{7}{2}}$
$$-\left[\frac{2}{3}(1 -t^2)(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{8}{15}t(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{8}{15}\left(\frac{2}{7}(t+1)^{\frac{7}{2}}\right)\right]$$

$$-\left[\frac{2}{3}(1 -t^2)(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{8}{15}t(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{16}{105}(t+1)^{\frac{7}{2}} \right]$$

$$-\frac{2}{3}(1 -t^2)(1+ t)^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{8}{15}t(t + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} + \frac{16}{105}(t+1)^{\frac{7}{2}}$$
Let $t = \sin x$

> $$I = -\frac{2}{3}(\cos^2x)(1+ \sin x)^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{8}{15}\sin x(\sin x + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} + \frac{16}{105}(\sin x+1)^{\frac{7}{2}} + C$$

Comment: The derivative of sin(x) is not -cos(x). So where does the minus come from?